# I need help...........sample project

Tags: asp.net

Can anybody give me one sample Asp.Net Project where all the Object oriented concept like class, abstraction, polymorphism, Inheritance and array list has been used for my practice purpose.

I am new to this platform i know all the above mentioned concept but i don't know where and how to use those concept in web application.

Comment: I suggest you search via google. There is no quick way to answer your question...

Comment: Hi..still i have not got my expected project.I want to develop web application using object oriented concept in asp dot net.could somebody please help me how to start?......

Answer (score 3):

Download from : http://www.dotnetspider.com/

Available sample projects over there are :

1. Course Finder - Search Colleges and Courses
2. Library Management System
3. Student Project - Personal Assistant
4. Academic Project - Address Book
5. School Management System